# 'mat-tree' is not a known element:

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I get and error  when I try to add the expmle tree of material.angular

ERROR in src/app/features/itemmonitor/data-options-tree/data-options-tree.component.html:1:1 - error NG8001: 'mat-tree' is not a known element:
1. If 'mat-tree' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'mat-tree' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

data-options-tree.component.spec.ts

```
<mat-tree>
  <mat-tree-node> parent node </mat-tree-node>
  <mat-tree-node> -- child node1 </mat-tree-node>
  <mat-tree-node> -- child node2 </mat-tree-node>
</mat-tree>
```

item-monitor.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { DataOptionsTreeComponent } from './data-options-tree/data-options-tree.component';
import { MatTreeModule } from '@angular/material/tree';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [DataOptionsTreeComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    MatTreeModule,
  ],
})
export class ItemMonitorModule { }
```

My package.json dependencies

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~9.1.9",
    "@angular/cdk": "~9.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "~9.1.9",
    "@angular/compiler": "~9.1.9",
    "@angular/core": "~9.1.9",
    "@angular/forms": "~9.1.9",
    "@angular/material": "~9.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~9.1.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~9.1.9",
    "@angular/router": "~9.1.9",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.5",
    "thrift": "git+https://github.com/apache/thrift.git",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.3"
  },
```

Comment: Also put it in declarations. might be worked.

Comment: try to restart ng serve, sometimes it helps

Comment: Did you ever figure this one out? I'm running into a similar issue with mat-icon.

Comment: I tried a lot of  things And I don't remember exactly what fixed it.  But I remember was not a code fix. Something about cleaning caches, delete node_modules, delete package-lock.json, restart everything and so on. Sorry not to be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
rm -rf node_modules/
npm install
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Perform the following steps:

- Delete `node_modules` folder
- Delete `package-lock.json` (Or `yarn.lock` for yarn)
- npm install (Or `yarn install`)
- `ng serve`

Answer (score 0):

This was happening to me. It happened because I'd forgotten to add the component containing the tree to the declarations section of app.module.ts

I think this means that the component was excluded due to tree shaking - and so the tree module was not included, but the html was still parsed/ validated