# 'mat-tree' is not a known element:, everything is imported still doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "install:clean": "rm -rf node_modules/ && rm -rf package-lock.json && npm install && ng serve -o"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "6.11.1",
    "npm": "3.10.9"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "13.3.1",
    "@angular/cdk": "^13.3.9",
    "@angular/common": "^13.3.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "^13.3.1",
    "@angular/core": "^13.3.1",
    "@angular/elements": "^13.3.1",
    "@angular/forms": "^13.3.1",
    "@angular/material": "^13.3.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^13.3.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^13.3.1",
    "@angular/platform-server": "13.3.1",
    "@angular/router": "^13.3.1",
    "ajv": "8.11.0",
    "angular-material-tree": "^0.2.1",
    "arrive": "2.4.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.6.1",
    "bootstrap-material-design": "4.1.3",
    "bootstrap-notify": "3.1.3",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.3",
    "chartist": "0.11.4",
    "classlist.js": "1.1.20150312",
    "core-js": "3.21.1",
    "eslint": "^8.11.0",
    "express": "4.17.3",
    "googleapis": "99.0.0",
    "hammerjs": "2.0.8",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "moment": "2.29.2",
    "ng2-charts": "^2.4.2",
    "perfect-scrollbar": "1.5.5",
    "popper.js": "1.16.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "rxjs": "^7.5.5",
    "rxjs-compat": "6.6.7",
    "typedjson": "^1.8.0",
    "web-animations-js": "2.3.2",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^13.3.1",
    "@angular/cli": "^13.3.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^13.3.1",
    "@angular/language-service": "13.3.1",
    "@types/bootstrap": "4.5.0",
    "@types/chartist": "0.11.1",
    "@types/google.maps": "3.47.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.10.3",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.10",
    "@types/jquery": "3.5.6",
    "@types/node": "16.3.2",
    "codelyzer": "6.0.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.0.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~7.0.0",
    "karma": "^6.3.17",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.1",
    "karma-coverage": "^2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.7.0",
    "protractor": "7.0.0",
    "sass": "1.32.13",
    "ts-node": "~10.7.0",
    "tslint": "6.1.3",
    "typescript": "~4.4.2"
  }
}
```

```js
import {SelectionModel} from '@angular/cdk/collections';
import {FlatTreeControl} from '@angular/cdk/tree';
import {Component, Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {MatTreeFlatDataSource, MatTreeFlattener} from '@angular/material/tree';
import {BehaviorSubject} from 'rxjs';

/**
 * Node for to-do item
 */
export class TodoItemNode {
  children: TodoItemNode[];
  item: string;
}

/** Flat to-do item node with expandable and level information */
export class TodoItemFlatNode {
  item: string;
  level: number;
  expandable: boolean;
}

/**
 * The Json object for to-do list data.
 */
const TREE_DATA = {
  Groceries: {
    'Almond Meal flour': null,
    'Organic eggs': null,
    'Protein Powder': null,
    Fruits: {
      Apple: null,
      Berries: ['Blueberry', 'Raspberry'],
      Orange: null,
    },
  },
  Reminders: ['Cook dinner', 'Read the Material Design spec', 'Upgrade Application to Angular'],
};

/**
 * Checklist database, it can build a tree structured Json object.
 * Each node in Json object represents a to-do item or a category.
 * If a node is a category, it has children items and new items can be added under the category.
 */
@Injectable()
export class ChecklistDatabase {
  dataChange = new BehaviorSubject<TodoItemNode[]>([]);

  get data(): TodoItemNode[] {
    return this.dataChange.value;
  }

  constructor() {
    this.initialize();
  }

  initialize() {
    // Build the tree nodes from Json object. The result is a list of `TodoItemNode` with nested
    //     file node as children.
    const data = this.buildFileTree(TREE_DATA, 0);

    // Notify the change.
    this.dataChange.next(data);
  }

  /**
   * Build the file structure tree. The `value` is the Json object, or a sub-tree of a Json object.
   * The return value is the list of `TodoItemNode`.
   */
  buildFileTree(obj: {[key: string]: any}, level: number): TodoItemNode[] {
    return Object.keys(obj).reduce<TodoItemNode[]>((accumulator, key) => {
      const value = obj[key];
      const node = new TodoItemNode();
      node.item = key;

      if (value != null) {
        if (typeof value === 'object') {
          node.children = this.buildFileTree(value, level + 1);
        } else {
          node.item = value;
        }
      }

      return accumulator.concat(node);
    }, []);
  }

  /** Add an item to to-do list */
  insertItem(parent: TodoItemNode, name: string) {
    if (parent.children) {
      parent.children.push({item: name} as TodoItemNode);
      this.dataChange.next(this.data);
    }
  }

  updateItem(node: TodoItemNode, name: string) {
    node.item = name;
    this.dataChange.next(this.data);
  }
}

/**
 * @title Tree with checkboxes
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'app-file-data',
  templateUrl: './file-data.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./file-data.component.css']
})
export class FileDataComponent {
  /** Map from flat node to nested node. This helps us finding the nested node to be modified */
  flatNodeMap = new Map<TodoItemFlatNode, TodoItemNode>();

  /** Map from nested node to flattened node. This helps us to keep the same object for selection */
  nestedNodeMap = new Map<TodoItemNode, TodoItemFlatNode>();

  /** A selected parent node to be inserted */
  selectedParent: TodoItemFlatNode | null = null;

  /** The new item's name */
  newItemName = '';

  treeControl: FlatTreeControl<TodoItemFlatNode>;

  treeFlattener: MatTreeFlattener<TodoItemNode, TodoItemFlatNode>;

  dataSource: MatTreeFlatDataSource<TodoItemNode, TodoItemFlatNode>;

  /** The selection for checklist */
  checklistSelection = new SelectionModel<TodoItemFlatNode>(true /* multiple */);

  constructor(private _database: ChecklistDatabase) {
    this.treeFlattener = new MatTreeFlattener(
      this.transformer,
      this.getLevel,
      this.isExpandable,
      this.getChildren,
    );
    this.treeControl = new FlatTreeControl<TodoItemFlatNode>(this.getLevel, this.isExpandable);
    this.dataSource = new MatTreeFlatDataSource(this.treeControl, this.treeFlattener);

    _database.dataChange.subscribe(data => {
      this.dataSource.data = data;
    });
  }

  getLevel = (node: TodoItemFlatNode) => node.level;

  isExpandable = (node: TodoItemFlatNode) => node.expandable;

  getChildren = (node: TodoItemNode): TodoItemNode[] => node.children;

  hasChild = (_: number, _nodeData: TodoItemFlatNode) => _nodeData.expandable;

  hasNoContent = (_: number, _nodeData: TodoItemFlatNode) => _nodeData.item === '';

  /**
   * Transformer to convert nested node to flat node. Record the nodes in maps for later use.
   */
  transformer = (node: TodoItemNode, level: number) => {
    const existingNode = this.nestedNodeMap.get(node);
    const flatNode =
      existingNode && existingNode.item === node.item ? existingNode : new TodoItemFlatNode();
    flatNode.item = node.item;
    flatNode.level = level;
    flatNode.expandable = !!node.children?.length;
    this.flatNodeMap.set(flatNode, node);
    this.nestedNodeMap.set(node, flatNode);
    return flatNode;
  };

  /** Whether all the descendants of the node are selected. */
  descendantsAllSelected(node: TodoItemFlatNode): boolean {
    const descendants = this.treeControl.getDescendants(node);
    const descAllSelected =
      descendants.length > 0 &&
      descendants.every(child => {
        return this.checklistSelection.isSelected(child);
      });
    return descAllSelected;
  }

  /** Whether part of the descendants are selected */
  descendantsPartiallySelected(node: TodoItemFlatNode): boolean {
    const descendants = this.treeControl.getDescendants(node);
    const result = descendants.some(child => this.checklistSelection.isSelected(child));
    return result && !this.descendantsAllSelected(node);
  }

  /** Toggle the to-do item selection. Select/deselect all the descendants node */
  todoItemSelectionToggle(node: TodoItemFlatNode): void {
    this.checklistSelection.toggle(node);
    const descendants = this.treeControl.getDescendants(node);
    this.checklistSelection.isSelected(node)
      ? this.checklistSelection.select(...descendants)
      : this.checklistSelection.deselect(...descendants);

    // Force update for the parent
    descendants.forEach(child => this.checklistSelection.isSelected(child));
    this.checkAllParentsSelection(node);
  }

  /** Toggle a leaf to-do item selection. Check all the parents to see if they changed */
  todoLeafItemSelectionToggle(node: TodoItemFlatNode): void {
    this.checklistSelection.toggle(node);
    this.checkAllParentsSelection(node);
  }

  /* Checks all the parents when a leaf node is selected/unselected */
  checkAllParentsSelection(node: TodoItemFlatNode): void {
    let parent: TodoItemFlatNode | null = this.getParentNode(node);
    while (parent) {
      this.checkRootNodeSelection(parent);
      parent = this.getParentNode(parent);
    }
  }

  /** Check root node checked state and change it accordingly */
  checkRootNodeSelection(node: TodoItemFlatNode): void {
    const nodeSelected = this.checklistSelection.isSelected(node);
    const descendants = this.treeControl.getDescendants(node);
    const descAllSelected =
      descendants.length > 0 &&
      descendants.every(child => {
        return this.checklistSelection.isSelected(child);
      });
    if (nodeSelected && !descAllSelected) {
      this.checklistSelection.deselect(node);
    } else if (!nodeSelected && descAllSelected) {
      this.checklistSelection.select(node);
    }
  }

  /* Get the parent node of a node */
  getParentNode(node: TodoItemFlatNode): TodoItemFlatNode | null {
    const currentLevel = this.getLevel(node);

    if (currentLevel < 1) {
      return null;
    }

    const startIndex = this.treeControl.dataNodes.indexOf(node) - 1;

    for (let i = startIndex; i >= 0; i--) {
      const currentNode = this.treeControl.dataNodes[i];

      if (this.getLevel(currentNode) < currentLevel) {
        return currentNode;
      }
    }
    return null;
  }

  /** Select the category so we can insert the new item. */
  addNewItem(node: TodoItemFlatNode) {
    const parentNode = this.flatNodeMap.get(node);
    this._database.insertItem(parentNode!, '');
    this.treeControl.expand(node);
  }

  /** Save the node to database */
  saveNode(node: TodoItemFlatNode, itemValue: string) {
    const nestedNode = this.flatNodeMap.get(node);
    this._database.updateItem(nestedNode!, itemValue);
  }
}
```

```html
<mat-tree [dataSource]="dataSource" [treeControl]="treeControl">
    <mat-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let node" matTreeNodeToggle matTreeNodePadding>
      <button mat-icon-button disabled></button>
      <mat-checkbox class="checklist-leaf-node"
                    [checked]="checklistSelection.isSelected(node)"
                    (change)="todoLeafItemSelectionToggle(node)">{{node.item}}</mat-checkbox>
    </mat-tree-node>
  
    <mat-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let node; when: hasNoContent" matTreeNodePadding>
      <button mat-icon-button disabled></button>
      <mat-form-field appearance="fill">  
        <mat-label>New item...</mat-label>
        <input matInput #itemValue placeholder="Ex. Lettuce">
      </mat-form-field>
      <button mat-button (click)="saveNode(node, itemValue.value)">Save</button>
    </mat-tree-node>
  
    <mat-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let node; when: hasChild" matTreeNodePadding>
      <button mat-icon-button matTreeNodeToggle
              [attr.aria-label]="'Toggle ' + node.item">
        <mat-icon class="mat-icon-rtl-mirror">
          {{treeControl.isExpanded(node) ? 'expand_more' : 'chevron_right'}}
        </mat-icon>
      </button>
      <mat-checkbox [checked]="descendantsAllSelected(node)"
                    [indeterminate]="descendantsPartiallySelected(node)"
                    (change)="todoItemSelectionToggle(node)">{{node.item}}</mat-checkbox>
      <button mat-icon-button (click)="addNewItem(node)"><mat-icon>add</mat-icon></button>
    </mat-tree-node>
  </mat-tree>
```

Comment: please share the code, especially the module where material is imported

Comment: maybe you forgot to import the module import {MatTreeModule} from '@angular/material/tree' in your module

Comment: I imported everything to as best of knowledge, i have imported it in app.module.ts, in component also, I tried deleting and reinstalling node_modules aslo. Nothing worked!

Comment: @Divyamishra Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62264033/mat-tree-is-not-a-known-element) help?

Comment: @NarenMurali I am so sorry but no didn't work.

Comment: @Divyamishra are you using this component in a lazy loaded module? then that moduel needs to import `MatTreeModule` and others also!

Comment: you need import the `MatTreeModule` in the **module** (include in imports array) where you declare your **component** or a module that export this module, e.g. typical you has material.module with exports [MatThreeModule] and you import the MaterialModule.

Comment: @NarenMurali thank you it worked. I was only importing in app.module.ts